# Tutorial for working with Texpad on iPad Pro

Tags: texpad, ipad

I have written my PhD thesis with TexStudio on my laptop. Now I’m travelling and have to modify my thesis, but I only have an iPad with me. All my documents are on Dropbox and so I downloaded Texpad, hoping to open my files on this app. It seems, however, that this is more complicated than I thought and I can’t find any tutorial or good explanation of this app.

Even though I have all relevant files for my thesis in one dropbox folder that I can access in the file browser, Texpad only gives me error messages. I can’t find any of the important commands either, like compile or change from PDFLatex to Xelatex. I don’t even know if the standard option id PDFLatex.

Basically, my question is, has anybody been working with this app and could tell me you to use it myself ? Or where to find a tutorial? 
[image]

Comment: If you google your title, then this handy guide comes up: https://www.texpad.com/guide/ios

Comment: Online services such as overleaf or sharelatex may be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks AML, but this guide is not for iPad and not for the recent version of TexPad. My version is quite different

Comment: I shifted from Texpad, the first iPad app I tried, to TeX Writer some years ago and I find it works much better. I use it daily without problems

Comment: Thank you Raoul Kessels! TeX Writer does seem to be much easier, but somehow the app shuts always down before it finishes compiling. Do you know what I can do ?

Comment: I am using version v20171118.1831 on an iPad Air 2 with iOS 10.3.3 and it works fine. I should try with a minimal doc. Rember that to load packages for the first time you need internet connection.